# Drools Business Rules : Unable to determine what is this NULL in exception detail and What these number with colon

Tags: java, drools, rules, bpmn, rule-engine

I am using Drools BPMN rule engine for business rules validation and getting below errors intermittently in my application.

**Exception while executing rules. [determine_flow_name:1 - Determine Flow Name Setup:3] -- [poareqflow:6 - POA Flow Setup:17] -- [poareqflow:6 - App Request:43] -- [poareqflow:6 - SDM Mapping:28] -- [poareqflow:6 - SDMEnrichment:41] – null**

I am looking for below information.

1. How can I know more about what is this NULL , I changed log level to TRACE but no more information on logs.
2. What are these number with colon : **SDMEnrichment:41** [They are not line number for sure]

Any help is much appreciated

Comment: would help if you share the bpmn file as the process flow needs to be clearly understood to answer the question

Comment: @DebDas I would love to but I am not allowed to as per company policy

Comment: so create an anonymized example which still causes the same problem and share that.

Comment: @VishalPardava you can write an example without actually using the business models